How to Delete a row from dataverse based on collection in power apps?
I created a gallery which displays the dataverse table details based on the selected items in combobox.
I created a collection named "DisplayCollectionvalues", which is created based on gallery.
ClearCollect(DisplayCollectionvalues, Gallery6.AllItems);
now collection  is formatted like dataverse structure. Now when i delete the collection , i want to delete its corresponding data in dataverse. how to achieve this?
I tried by creating a flow in power automate to change the collection into JSON format and passing the columns to the delete a row in dataverse option. but unfortunately not able to convert the collection into JSON . please advice on this.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is not very clear - please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some tips on asking a good question. What do you mean when you say that you "delete the collection"? Is it deleting a specific item from a collection? And to "delete its corresponding data", do you mean for every item in your collection, you want to delete the corresponding record from Dataverse?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
